# How can I, using java, determine whether a certain event took place this week, last week or which week?

Tags: java, calendar

I am working on a simple point of sale system and was trying to generate as much stats on the sales and expense data as possible. I wanted a way to show sales for this week but, though, I went through the api and checked up some tutorials, I could not really find a way to do it. Finally, I decided to compare the `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` the transaction took place to the `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` of today. As in, if they were the same, the transaction must have taken place in the same week as today, this week, that is. At first, it seemed to work but am having second thoughts about it now. I would appreciate it a lot if someone pointed the right way to go about it to me.

```
public void getSalesTotalForWeek() throws SQLException {
    //getDatesCount() populates a collection(listDates) with dates in which
    //transactions took place
    getDatesCount();
    //sets cal with today's date
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; listDates.size(); i++) {
        //set c with the date of when the transaction took place
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(listDates.get(i).substring(0, 4)),
        Integer.parseInt(listDates.get(i).substring(5, 7)), Integer.parseInt(listDates.get(i).substring(8, 10)));
        //This is like saying if the day of week in month when the transaction took place
        //is the same as that of today, then the transaction
        //must have taken place in the same week as today
        if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) == c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH)){
            rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM transaction_history where Time like '"+   listDates.get(i) + "%'");
            while (rst.next()) {
                weekSalesTotal += rst.getInt(2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to fix in your code:

```
public void getSalesTotalForWeek()
```

Method named `get*()` doesn't really return anything (counterintuitive). Seems like `weekSalesTotal` is a field, remember about thread safety.

---

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
```

What if one day someone asks you for sales of last week? Or the first week of March? Consider passing both start date and end date as arguments. Also are you sure you want to use server-default time zone?

---

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(listDates.get(i).substring(0, 4)),
Integer.parseInt(listDates.get(i).substring(5, 7)), Integer.parseInt(listDates.get(i).substring(8, 10)));
```

`listDates` is a `List<String>`? Consider `Date` type instead, the code above looks bad.

---

```
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) == c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH)
```

I don't quite get this code. I'm reading the JavaDoc of [`DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) and I still don't get it...

---

```
"SELECT * FROM transaction_history where Time like '"+   listDates.get(i) + "%'"
```

Don't select all columns if you are interested only in the second (let's call it `value`). Also don't concatenate SQLs, SQL-injection is already on the way. Finally using `like` operator for dates? Are you using proper `DATE` type in database?

---

Is `weekSalesTotal` a field? Remember about synchronization. And avoid running SQL in a loop.

## TL;DR

I believe you whole method can be replaced with something much more powerful, faster and simpler:

```
public int getSalesTotalWithin(Date start, Date end) {
  rst = stmt.executeQuery(
    "SELECT SUM(value) FROM transaction_history where Time BETWEEN ? AND ?");
  return rst.getInt(1);
}
```

This is only pseudo-code, it misses JDBC boilerplater and `?` substitution. But you'll get the idea. Now you can call it with any date range, e.g:

```
Calendar weekAgo = new GregorianCalendar();
weekAgo.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
getSalesTotalWithin(weekAgo.getTime(), new Date());
```

If you want statistics since last Monday:

```
Calendar lastMonday = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
lastMonday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
lastMonday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
//...zero other fields
getSalesTotalWithin(lastMonday.getTime(), new Date());
```

Comment: Am a total beginner in java and sql so, pardon me. That was my best shot. And yes weekSalesTotal is a field and am using DATETIME type in the database. Thanks a lot. Your answer has really opened my eyes. By the way, what is wrong with using server-default time zone? That was all I had.

Comment: @Muaad: imagine your application is deployed in USA. Or Europe. Or Australia. The same date will be interpreted in a different way because each server has a different time zone, thus producing different results.

Comment: Got that. By the way, when I say this week, it doesn't have to be 7 days before today as your code seems to suggest. What I mean is that if weeks start on mondays and today is thursday, for example, this week includes monday, tuesday, wednesday and thursday (4 days). So, as days go by, days in the week increase by one till you get to monday again when the new week starts. I was looking for a way to calculate sales total for week like that. How can java know today is in the same week as any other given day based on what I said above? Thanks.

Comment: @Muaad: method I suggested is flexible enough to handle your case as well, see example at the very bottom.